# How to use pbrun in a bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

In interactive mode, I do

```
pbrun su - privuser
rm dir1
```

But if I run above commands in a bash script file, I'll simply receive a new bash terminal window after the first command.

Is it possible use `pbrun` in a script file?

Comment: Not familiar with `pbrun`, but maybe `pbrun -u someone rm dir1`

Answer (score 0):

yes, You can use pbrun and su command in your bash script.but before that

pbrun - It is a secured terminal command where
sudo- is secured user instead of terminal.

So, If you have valid credentials, you can use below command

pbrun -u [username] dap --> syntax

Try using " pbrun -u privuser" --> It might work